# Ubuntu 14.04 five continuously beeps

Tags: 14.04, hardware

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 LTS when it was released, and a couple of weeks before, my laptop started to beep. The five beeps starts when I turn on the laptop, before the GRUB page appear. When I execute the command `sudo lshw | head -30` in Terminal, I get:

```
desciption: Portable computer
product: Inspiron N5110 (To be filled by O.E.M.)
manufacturer: Dell Inc.
version: Not Specified
serial: HXQS8S1
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.6 dmi-2.6 vsyscall32
configuration: boot=normal chassis=portable sku=To be filled by O.E.M. uuid=44454C4C-5800-1051-8053-C8C04F385331
*-core
   desciption: Motherboard
   product: 06XGFH
   manufacturer: Dell Inc.
   physical ID: 0
   version: A09
   serial: .HXQS8S1.BR108192390088.
   slot: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
 *-cpu
      desciption: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz
      manufacturer: Intel Corp.
      physical ID: 4
      bus information: cpu@0
      version: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2450M CPU @ 2.50GHz
      serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      slot: CPU 1
      width: 800MHz
      capability: 800MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 100MHz
```

Sometimes, when I reboot my computer, these beeps disappear. But since the last days, this is not working anymore.

**EDIT:**

Following the advice of Charles Green (in comments), I found in [this](http://blog.parts-people.com/2014/06/25/dell-inspiron-15r-n5110-beep-codes-diagnostic-indicators/) website a list of DELL N5110 beeps.

`5 beeps: Real Time Clock (RTC) power fail | CMOS battery failure`

Ok, I'm very newbie. What should I do to fix that?

Comment: This may be a hardware problem - check the Dell website for the technical manual for your computer, and see if it mentions the BIOS beeping if there is a problem.

Comment: @CharlesGreen I followed your advice and edited the post with the info I've found about Dell beeps.

Comment: The CMOS battery is usually found on the motherboard. The Dell technical manual for your computer should indicate how to change it and with what type of battery required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Real-Time clock failure is indicating that the motherboard of your computer needs to have it's battery replaced - this is a coin-type battery, available generally at supermarkets, drugstores and hardware stores.  The Dell documentation will tell you where on the motherboard to find it, and how to replace it.

Comment: If someone with a Dell Inspiron 15R (N5110) wants to change your motherboard battery, the battery needs to be a CR2032 Lithium 3V. I had changed and my laptop is working fine, without that beeps of hell :) Thank you one more time, @CharlesGreen

Comment: @WilliamKennedy  Glad to hear that it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I have a Dell Inspiron N5110 that starts beeping continuously in sets of 5 immediately after the power button is pressed. I've found no problems with the computer, it boots Ubuntu 16.04, and runs everything as expected. I know that 5 beeps is a sign to replace the CMOS battery but frankly at this point the computer is not worth it. I just wanted the beeping to stop. Fortunately I discovered that if I endure the beeps until the Ubuntu login screen then I can close the lid of the laptop and they stop. I can then open the lid again and login, the beeps never come back until the computer is restarted.